# How can I get location from app in background/foreground after every 5 min

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

How can I get it?

```
-(void)updateLocation {

[self performSelector:@selector(updateLocation) withObject:nil afterDelay:300];

[self.locationTracker updateLocationToServer];
}
```

but it's not working every time.

Comment: What are you doing in updateLocation function? Just curious..

Comment: @iphonic its recurring function call every 5 min and get updated location

Comment: That's wrong to use Timer or performSelector to fetch GPS location, 1. You don't need this, `CLLocationManager` is capable of giving GPS locations as per settings/filters you have set to it even in background 2. Using timer, you must be starting GPS everytime and trying to get locations, the drawback of this you won't get exact location as GPS takes some seconds to position itself correctly.

Better use only `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: @iphonic : i used CLLocationManger«

Comment: Yes I know, without that you can't get GPS values, my point is you don't need Timer to get locations, `CLLocationManager` does that for you already.

Comment: @iphonic : I know that updatelocation work on distance filter but i need location on every 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NSTimer

```
NSInteger minutes = 5;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 * minutes
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateLocation)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Comment: @BhadreshSonani you can not get the location when the app got killed/terminated.

Answer (score 0):

For a location to be updated in background you need to turn background mode on from capabilities of your project.
[image]

Comment: So whats the exact problem you are facing. Can you please explain a little more.

Comment: i want to get location every 5 minutes interval time but some time i am getting perfact location on tiime but some time i am not getting location.

Answer (score 0):

Add the permission for background location updates in Capabilities as suggested by NA000022 and add this to your location manager.

```
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
```

I would also suggest to use

```
locationManager.distanceFilter 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy
```

rather than updating it for time duration. Since location updates consume battery faster than any other services.

Comment: i already done that,     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

Comment: What about the top line? Have you added that code? I have worked on a similar thing recently and it is working good in background/foreground.